# Magento 1.9 custom soap api module cannot get product final price from collection

Tags: magento-1.9, price, product-collection, soap-api-v2

I created a custom module that extends the core API with a new method that allows me to get a product collection based on specific filters. The method works so far, but I am having issues with the final price. This is what I have now:

```
$product_collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('final_price')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('season')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('product_category')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('activity')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('gender')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('material')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('color')
        ->setOrder('entity', 'DESC')
        ->setPageSize(10);
```

The above works just fine, but when I try adding `->addFinalPrice()`, the collection comes up empty. I have used `->addFinalPrice()` before in another module, and it works just fine, so I am at a loss as to what is different this time...

Anyone care to elaborate?